# How to enable the console on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, civilization-6

I know that I just need to set DebugPanel to 1 in the config.ini but where does the config file live on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the Debug Menu in Civilization VI:

1. Go to: `~/Library/Application Support/Sid Meier's Civilization VI`
2. Open `AppOptions.txt`, then change the line `EnableDebugMenu 0` to `EnableDebugMenu 1`